# php mysql can't multiply a mysql result and a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I can't for the life of me figure out why i keep coming up with 0 on this ... i'm pulling a price from one of my tables and multiplying it by the quantity they are putting in in the form ... for some reason it when i try and do the math, it keeps coming up as 0 ... any help?

code:

```
$get_code = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE p_code LIKE '%$po_code%'";
$run_code = mysqli_query($con, $get_code); 
$row_code = mysqli_fetch_array($run_code);

$count = $_POST['ord_amt'];
$price = $row_code['p_price'];

$sum_total = $price * $count;
```

form code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php 
include('includes/connection.php'); 
global $con; 

$cust = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = '".$_SESSION['u_id']."'";
$r_cs = mysqli_query($con, $cust); 
$rw_c = mysqli_fetch_array($r_cs); 

echo "<input type='hidden' name='c_id' value='".$rw_c['c_id']."'>";
?>
    <table id="datatable1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Distal Opening</th>
                <th>Material</th>
                <th>Ply</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>Options</th>
                <th>Or Enter Code (If Known)</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="prod" id="selectProd" onchange="get_prod(this.value)" required="required">
                        <?php get_prod_kind() ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="opening" id="distOpen" required="required">
                        <option value="">Select Opening</option>
                        <option value="1">Rubberized Reinforced</option>
                        <option value="2">Standard Opening</option>
                        <option value="">None</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name='mat' id="selectMat" onchange="get_ply(this.value)" required="required">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>    
                    <select class="form-control" name="ply" id="plySelect" onchange="get_size(this.value)" required="required">
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="size" id="sizeSelect" onchange="get_len(this.value)" required="required">
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="length" id="selectLength" required="required">
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="opts" required="required">
                        <option value="">Select Options</option>
                        <option value="1">Sewn Top (S)</option>
                        <option value="2">Seal-In-Liner (C)</option>
                        <option value="">None</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' name='cust_code'></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' name='ord_amt' required="required"></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

    <button class="button button-3d button-rounded button-aqua" name="p_order"><i class="icon-repeat"></i>Next Item</button>
    <button class="button button-3d button-rounded button-green"><i class="icon-ok"></i>Submit Order</button>

</form>
```

Comment: `var_dump($row_code, $count);` gives what?

Comment: before you calculate check if you have values in your variables.

Comment: Could we have the form code?

Comment: var_dump() gives me the same results ...

Comment: ...which are? `$row_code` should give you an array though.

Comment: the same result is a 0 ... var_dump() didn't work for this for some reason

Comment: `var_dump()` works perfectly if you just place it the right place :-) Put it directly after `$row_code = mysqli_fetch_array($run_code);` - and let us know what the result of that was.

Comment: i put it there ... the math is still coming up with a 0 with it ... i put it exactly where you said and how you said, and the math is still giving me a 0

Comment: The result of your multiplication won't change - `var_dump()` is a useful function to help debug, it lets you know what variables are, their values and types.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.